# Comparing 2 columns and output the difference in a new table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to compare Part A and Part B and output the difference (Part A - Part B) into a new column as absolute values.

| Part A | Part B |
| --- | --- |
| 49.56 | 50.00 |
| 49.99 | 50.50 |
| 50.12 | 50.10 |
| 50.51 | 50.50 |

Comment: So what did you try? Where are you stuck? What is your question?

Comment: The title of your question talks about a new table, the body of your question talks about a new column. Which do you want? Or do you actually only want a `SELECT` result that has an additional column?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ABS` function:

```
SELECT "Part A", "Part B", ABS("Part A" - "Part B") abs_value FROM your_table
```